# Как настроить/подключить `webpack config` c `laravel-mix-criticalcss`?

Tags: javascript, laravel, frontend, webpack4, laravel-mix

Как в моем случае правильно настроить/подключить `webpack config`?

файл **webpack.mix.js**

```js
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

// var LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");
// mix.sassResources("resources/scss/_variables.scss");

mix.webpackConfig({
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: "commons"
    },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: "styles",
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          chunks: "all",
          enforce: true,
          minChunks: 1,
          name: "css/style",
          filename: "css/styles.js",
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        },
        commons: {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          chunks: "all",
          minChunks: 2,
          name: "commons",
          filename: "commons.js",
          enforce: true,
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // filename: "style.css",
      ignoreOrder: false // Enable to remove warnings about conflicting order
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "resolve-url-loader"
          },
          "sass-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              plugins: [
                autoprefixer({
                  // browsers: ["ie >= 8", "last 4 version"]
                })
              ],
              sourceMap: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-resources-loader",
            options: {
              resources: [
                "resources/scss/_variables.scss",
                "resources/scss/_mixins.scss"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: [
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",

              [
                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                {
                  regenerator: true
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: "pug-loader",
        options: {
          globals: true,
          // alias: { components: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/components") },
          pretty: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65
              },
              optipng: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                speed: 4
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              webp: {
                quality: 75
              }
            }
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
});

mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/index/index.js", "public/js/index.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/about/about.js", "public/js/about.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/login/login.js", "public/js/login.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/forgot-pass/forgot-pass.js", "public/js/forgot-pass.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/registration/registration.js", "public/js/registration.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/registration-ok/registration-ok.js", "public/js/registration-ok.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/restore-pass/restore-pass.js", "public/js/restore-pass.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-action/cabinet-action.js", "public/js/cabinet-action.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-basket/cabinet-basket.js", "public/js/cabinet-basket.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-favorites/cabinet-favorites.js", "public/js/cabinet-favorites.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-events/cabinet-events.js", "public/js/cabinet-events.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-settings/cabinet-settings.js", "public/js/cabinet-settings.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-history/cabinet-history.js", "public/js/cabinet-history.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-study/cabinet-study.js", "public/js/cabinet-study.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cabinet-chat/cabinet-chat.js", "public/js/cabinet-chat.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/pages-guide/pages-guide.js", "public/js/pages-guide.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/events/events.js", "public/js/events.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/blog/blog.js", "public/js/blog.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/products/products.js", "public/js/products.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/faq/faq.js", "public/js/faq.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.js", "public/js/privacy-policy.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/using-rules/using-rules.js", "public/js/using-rules.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/cookies/cookies.js", "public/js/cookies.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/blog-open/blog-open.js", "public/js/blog-open.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/404/404.js", "public/js/404.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/advantage/advantage.js", "public/js/advantage.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/collection/collection.js", "public/js/collection.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/collections/collections.js", "public/js/collections.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/ingredients/ingredients.js", "public/js/ingredients.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/contacts/contacts.js", "public/js/contacts.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/where-to-buy/where-to-buy.js", "public/js/where-to-buy.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/how-to-buy/how-to-buy.js", "public/js/how-to-buy.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/team/team.js", "public/js/team.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/style-guide/style-guide.js", "public/js/style-guide.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/search-result/search-result.js", "public/js/search-result.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/how-to-buy-partners/how-to-buy-partners.js", "public/js/how-to-buy-partners.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/event/event.js", "public/js/event.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/reviews/reviews.js", "public/js/reviews.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/product/product.js", "public/js/product.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/product-mob-preview/product-mob-preview.js", "public/js/product-mob-preview.js");
mix.js("resources/views/frontend/pages/product-mob-detail/product-mob-detail.js", "public/js/product-mob-detail.js");
mix.copyDirectory("resources/assets/images", "public/images");
mix.copyDirectory("resources/assets/fonts", "public/fonts");
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "laravel-mix-criticalcss": "^1.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "sass": "^1.24.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lazysizes": "^5.2.0",
    "pixi.js": "^5.2.0",
    "pixi.js-legacy": "^5.2.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

Ссылка на npm criticalcss
[пример из npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix-criticalcss)

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-criticalcss');

mix
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css')
  .criticalCss({
    enabled: mix.inProduction(),
    paths: {
      base: 'https://url-of-where-criticalcss-is-extracted.com/',
      templates: './where-critical-css-file-needs-to-be-written/',
      suffix: '_critical.min'
    },
    urls: [{
      url: 'blog',
      template: 'blog'
    }, ],
    options: {
      minify: true,
    },
  });
```